# What is the new name of Microsoft.Data.Entity.Ctp?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, code-first, ctp

I'm playing around with Entity Framework 4 and code only. The tutorial I'm following is using the Beta-Version of Visual Studio 2010 and is referring to Microsoft.Data.Entity.Ctp.
Since I'm working with the final release of Visual Studio the name of the dll must have changed.
Can somebody tell me how its name is now?

Cheers, AC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Code-only is still a CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=AF18E652-9EA7-478B-8B41-8424B94E3F58&displaylang=en&displaylang=en). It didn't ship in RTM. It will be a separate "Feature Pack" RSN.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a way to get noticed when the feature pack is released?

Comment: Follow the ADO.NET team blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2010/02/18/entity-framework-feature-ctp-3-now-available.aspx